# Jinja2 getting endif error even tho the tag is clearly ended

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I'm trying to append to a list during a loop.. I am getting an error about my {% if %} tag not being closed and encountering unknowntag 'hidden'. What am I missing here?

```
{% set hidden = [] %}
{% for row in packages %}
{% if row.hidden %}  #OPEN
{% hidden.append(row.id) %} #APPEND
{% endif %} # CLOSED
{% endfor %}
{% if hidden[0] %} # If my list isn't empty, show the next line
View Packages (Click here to show hidden)
{% else %}
View Packages # If list is empty show this line
{% endif %}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: show full error message and full template in question. If you use `extends` in template then show base template too.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason my hidden.append had to be inside another if statement..

```
{% set hidden = [] %}
{% for row in packages %}
{% if row.hidden %}  #OPEN
{% if hidden.append(row.id) %}{% endif %} #APPEND #THIS LINE
{% endif %} # CLOSED
{% endfor %}
{% if hidden[0] %} # If my list isn't empty, show the next line
View Packages (Click here to show hidden)
{% else %}
View Packages # If list is empty show this line
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Jinja2 is based on tags like an if tag or a set tag, but tags and python code is not the same. Especially you can not take any python code, put it in `{% %}` and expect it to work. Instead use the [`do` tag](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#expression-statement)

```
{% for row in packages %}
{% if row.hidden %}  #OPEN
{% do hidden.append(row.id) %}
{% endif %} # CLOSED
{% endfor %}
```

Your version with `if` worked because if executes the code and looks at the returnvalue. But you are not interested in the return value, so use a `do` tag.

The `do` expression is a extension so you need to load that for it to work.